# api validation for post body using jersey and swagger

Tags: rest, api, swagger, jersey-2.0

Am trying to build a REST post web service with a request body.
Using swagger and jersey for the same .

I have defined following for one of the attributes of the Body : ( contrived example )

```
 petType:
            description: Type of Pet
            type: string
            enum:
                - CAT
                - DOG
```

I would like to throw a http 400 exception in case of the incoming request not containing CAT or DOG.

However I am never getting a chance to handle the data and throw a Http 400 .
Instead in Postman I get a Http 500 .
Stacktrace :

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type au.com.xyz.PetRequest$PetTypeEnum from String "DONKEY": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [CAT, DOG] at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@12b7aa1a; line: 4, column: 14] (through reference chain: au.com.xyz.PetPromoRequest["petType"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:74)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1410)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:926)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer._deserializeAltString(EnumDeserializer.java:189)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:126)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:104)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1583)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:964)
```

So it looks like even before I get a chance to validate Jackson / swagger / jersey are doing some stuff - which I ideally dont want them to !

Any thoughts please ?

**UPDATE:**
Based on answer from Natasha have tried the following and it still does not work

option#1
Added @Priority annotation to the exception mapper:

```
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class AppExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<AppException> {
```

This did not work .

option#2
Added the following in web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.disableAutoDiscovery</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I keep getting the same exception:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type au.com.xyz.PetRequest$PetTypeEnum from String "DONKEY": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [CAT, DOG] at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@12b7aa1a; line: 4, column: 14] (through reference chain: au.com.xyz.PetPromoRequest["petType"])
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:74)
>   at com.f

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Jersey's auto discovery feature :
`resourceConfig.property(CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);` where resourceConfig is of type org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerConfig.

Here's an existing thread for Jersey's exception handler  : [Jersey unable to catch any Jackson Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615242/jersey-unable-to-catch-any-jackson-exception)

UPDATE:

For resolving Jackson error : value not one of declared Enum instance names

You can throw desired exception using `@JsonCreator` :

```
public enum PET {
    CAT("cat"),
    DOG("dog");

    private static MappingChange.Map<String, PET> FORMAT_MAP = Stream
            .of(PET.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.formatted, Function.identity()));

    private final String formatted;

    PET(String formatted) {
        this.formatted = formatted;
    }

    @JsonCreator // This is the factory method and must be static
    public static PET fromString(String string) {
               // Throw desirable exception here
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(FORMAT_MAP.get(string))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(string));
                
    }
}
```

Existing Thread: [Deserializing an enum with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689107/deserializing-an-enum-with-jackson)

Comment: Thanks Natasha based on your feedback I have tried a few more options but they have not worked . Please see my edited feedback based on your input

Comment: Hey Akila, I have updated the answer. Try the same and let us know.