# openapi generated Jackson with unknown Value for ENUM

Tags: jackson, openapi, swagger-codegen

I created a rest-api with openapi-codegen. As a parameter there is an object that contains two ENUMs.

e.g.

```
public enum DocumentType {
FOTO_ID("PHOTO_ID");
[...]
}
```

If i send a request with a DocumentType other than "PHOTO_ID" I get the following Response

```
Cannot construct instance of `[...]`, problem: Unexpected value '[...]'
at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 2, column: 21] (through reference chain: [...])
```

which is correct, but i would like to catch it and send my own ErrorResponse.

I could not find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has a similar problem, I just found a solution:

You have to set your own ExceptionMapper for JsonMappingException.
It is import to set a Priority, otherwise your Mapper will not be used.

```java
    @Named
    @Singleton
    @Provider
    @Priority(1)
    public class JsonMappingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException exception) {
        [...]
        }
    }
```

Credit to:
[Jersey unable to catch any Jackson Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615242/jersey-unable-to-catch-any-jackson-exception)
for pointing out the priority topic.